# Bibliography it's not working

Tags: bibliographies

So I have my citations in a JabRef database name "Biblio.bib".
I'm trying to make's the cites but it's not working.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Easdijasjdlkasdjl,znmxcm,nzxc,nmxcv,nmxcv,nmvxc,mnxcv,nmxvcljksvdoiupWE;JLK;JDS;LKJSDF;LJKASDF;LKJASDF;LJKADSFLJKADSFLJKSAFD;;FLSSL\cite{SOMEONE1998}.
\section{Bibliografía}
\printbibliography
\enddocument
```

Im getting this messages Proceso iniciado: /usr/texbin/bibtex "ReporteLujánEnLatex".aux

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: ReporteLujánEnLatex.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file ReporteLujánEnLatex.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ReporteLujánEnLatex.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ReporteLujánEnLatex.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

El proceso terminó con error(es)

Comment: Ddi you run _exactly_ the example you've posted? If so, you should get an error as `\printbibliography` is undefined.

Comment: I have this too

Comment: % Bibliografía
\bibliography{Biblio}
\usepackage{biblatex}

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the example, it works:

Put

```
\end{document}
```

instead of the wrong

```
\enddocument
```

and add this before \begin{document}

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{Biblio}
```

Note that the order of the lines is not what you wrote in the comment. You must load the package first.

Comment: Well, `\bibliography` should not be used with `biblatex`. More seriously, you need to run `biber` instead of `bibtex` to get the citation.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it. it not working